# Gitlab Secure Variables that are set in the build environment are not working with gitlab-ci file

Tags: node.js, strongloop, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using latest Gitlab infra as a repository and shared runner to build my code.

Currently I am trying to build and deploy **nodejs** application using **strong-pm**{running on my ec2 remote server with port 8701}. I can be able to build and deploy my build code from development system as well as from Gitlab defined in **gitlab-ci.yml** file via **http** from where **strongloop** has been installed:

```
- npm install -g strongloop 
- slc build --npm 
- slc deploy http://remote-host:8701 ../node-project-1.0.0.tgz 
   o/p: Deployed `../node-project-1.0.0.tgz` as `node-project` to `http://remote-host:8701/
```

When I try to deploy the same using secure connection, its working if I try to deploy it from my development system by setting environment variables:

```
$ sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/ec2.rsa 
$ export SSH_USER=ubuntu {amazon ec2 remote server user name}       
$ export SSH_KEY=~/.ssh/ec2.rsa {amazon ec2 remote server access key}   
$ slc deploy http+ssh://remote-host:8701
```

But when I try the same deploying from Gitlab infra as defined in gitlab-ci.yml file its giving:

```
        fs.js:634
      return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                     ^

    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    -
    -
   My SSH_KEY displayed here
    -
    -
   at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-deploy/bin/sl-deploy.js:112:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/lib/command.js:28:23
```

I have added my SSH_KEY and SSH_USER in **secret variables** {Project > Variables > Add Variable} option provided by Gitlab. And if i do `echo $SSH_USER` and `echo $SSH_USER` it displays the variables as i added in secrete variables.

My sample  gitlab-ci.yml file is here:

```
test:  
      stage: test
      script:
       - npm install -g strongloop
       - slc build --npm
       - echo $SSH_USER
       - echo $SSH_KEY  
       - slc deploy http+ssh://remote-host:8701 ../node-project-1.0.0.tgz
```

Please let me know if anyone could help me with this strange issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `~/.ssh/ec2.rsa` available in the runner?

Comment: Hi @mgansler. Thanks for your interest in helping me. As I have had mentioned I am using Gitlab infra as a repository and Gitlab shared runner. I have defined my SSH_KEY in secrete variables. So runner can read my SSH_KEY. Is there any possibility so that I directly set ~/.ssh/ec2.rsa path to shared runner? Thanks

Comment: Did you install the runner directly on the machine or are you using docker?
If you are using docker you may want to take a look here: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/ssh_keys/README.html
If you installed in on the host directly, it is running as a different user and you don't have access to your SSH KEYs.

Comment: I am using the default shared runner provided by GitLab.